# Linux (xcp-ng) installation has around 40GB of MS basic file system

Tags: linux, partitioning

So, I am having this trouble to get rid of these 3 partition that my Lenovo Thinkcenter keep creating when I install XCP-NG.

`fdisk -l` output:

[image: fdisk -l output]

So, basically I tried to remove those by `fdisk /dev/mountpoint` then when I press <kbd>d</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> it just says:

```
Command (m for help): d
No partition is defined yet!
```

Can you guys please help me to remove those three partitions and reclaim the space, because they are taking 40Gb of space?

[output from lsblk -l](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQQBz.png)

Comment: are they mounted, and what are they used for ? something like lsblk might give you more useful info than ol fdisk -l

Comment: so i did the lsblk -l and i have edited the post and added the output screenshot, i tried to unmount them and then just delete the partition, but it does not work. I installed Ubuntu on that system and this partition wont appear; however, when i install XCP-NG this partition reappear. This is a thinkcenter i3 7 gen which came with windows 10 pro.